# How to ask a user to make a choice

Tags: word-choice

I"am building a user interface for a web application and I have hit a brick wall for copy-writing.

Here is the premise:
I have a form where the user is given two options and must select one:

Option1 => Request a Copy

Option2 => Request Deletion

How do I ask the user what he/she would like to do?

It seems a little too blunt to just say "What do you want to do?", and "Select an Option" is too short i need something with at least 4 words to visually fill up enough space in the user interface.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Regards, Mike.

Comment: Those two options seem odd as the only possible choices.  What if I don't want a copy but also don't want to delete it?

Comment: @Jim These two options appear once the user clicks a "file options" link at the bottom of the user interface (if you don't want to delete it or copy it you wouldnt click the file options button).

Comment: So if you click "File Options"  what's wrong with two buttons that say "Copy"  and "Delete"?  No other words necessary.

Comment: @Jim the resulting pop-up will have too much white-space which creates a visual imbalance between the options and the submit buttons.

Comment: "Select a File Action"

Comment: Does adding "please" fill up the space?

Comment: “Select the Option that specifies what you want to do”    :-)    ⁠

Comment: Just use a really small font, and put "Given the two options we have preselected for you, please choose the one that most closely matches the option you would like to execute upon completion on your selection, or very near thereafter".